# How to get a string representation of hex?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/CG8gx/1/

```
for(var i = 0x00; i <= 0x88; i++){
    i = i.toString();
    if (i.length === 1) { 
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    // console.log(i.length);
    console.log(i);
    // console.log(decodeURIComponent("%" + i));
}
```

but `toString()` will give the decimal representation.  So the above code is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try this

```
for(var i = 0x00; i <= 0x88; i++){
    i = "0x" + i.toString(16);

    console.log(i);

}
```

will show

```
0x0
0x1
0x2
...
```